# c# program needed to startup on restart

Tags: c#

I was trying to build an application in c#, I converted the exe into hex, and then assigned to string hexo, I need the application to run on system restart automatically, and another problem I faced is that the application breaks and gives me error, it has stopped working or an invalid win 32 application.

My full program code is on pastebin, please take a look guys, and please tell me the startup code and where i should add the startup code and possibly help me with the application crash error.
I am using windows forms and .NET Framework 4.5.2 in visual studio 2015.

Here is my code:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        string hexo = ""; //Removed binary
        byte[] byt = StringToByteArrayFastest(hexo);
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load(byt);
        MethodInfo m = a.EntryPoint;
        var parameters = m.GetParameters().Length == 0 ? null : new[] { new string[0] };
        m.Invoke(null, parameters);
    }
    public static byte[] StringToByteArrayFastest(string hex)
    {
        if (hex.Length % 2 == 1)
            throw new Exception("The binary key cannot have an odd number of digits");

        byte[] arr = new byte[hex.Length >> 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length >> 1; ++i)
        {
            arr[i] = (byte)((GetHexVal(hex[i << 1]) << 4) + (GetHexVal(hex[(i << 1) + 1])));
        }

        return arr;
    }

    public static int GetHexVal(char hex)
    {
        int val = (int)hex;
        //For uppercase A-F letters:
        return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : 55);
        //For lowercase a-f letters:
        //return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : 87);
        //Or the two combined, but a bit slower:
        //return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : (val < 97 ? 55 : 87));
    }

}
```

Comment: please have a look above,its added

Comment: If you want to load the assembly, wouldn't it be easier to just load the binary image?

Comment: did you meant about the hexcode?

Comment: i took the hex code of the application,and the bit shifting was done to prevent the app crash

Comment: Ok, I have a new guess about what this is trying to do: You're trying to embed the assembly into your executable.  See also: `byte b = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16)`

Comment: yes i am adding the assembly to the executable,you are right,so where is the issue that causes the app to crash and where should i be be adding the code for startup and do u have that code?

Comment: why do I get the feeling that you are trying to build some kind of weird malware here?

Comment: why does changing assembly has to do something with malware

Comment: @Robert, because it's the sort of thing that malware would do and you have provided no legitimate reason for your doing it.

Comment: i just wanted ot to run at startup,and i have no intention to build a malware

Comment: Either your hex dump is corrupted, or the way you're decoding it is corrupting the assembly. That's what a `Bad Image Format` is. Also: you don't have to embed the assembly in order to run at startup.  [Windows provides a way to start an executable when the user logs into the computer.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [Multiple ways, actually](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: Went back in the edit history to the pastebin, and decoded it this morning out of a sense of morbid curiousity.  _It's not a .net image._  The exception trying to load it as a .net assembly is about the fact that it's got a _bad IL format._